# Can/should I change the scope of my question if I have had no responses?

Tags: discussion, questions

[I posted a question](https://superuser.com/questions/945426/dd-wrt-web-access-not-working) on Superuser a couple of days ago and have had no answers in response - a few comments yes, but no answers. I have found out what was causing the issue I am having, but not how to overcome/fix it.

The question is now eligible for a bounty and I am very keen to get an answer.

I am unsure whether it is acceptable to edit the original question and effectively change the question from

> What is causing problem X?

to

> How do I fix problem X?

now that I have more information (effectively creating a more informative and constructive question). I personally don't see it as an issue to edit the original question as I have had no answers, so there is no chance of me invalidating any existing responses.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Do it if it gets the same information you were originally looking for: **How to fix problem X**.

Looking at the comments, you mention something that is very crucial to addressing the original issue, and that should *definitely* be edited into your question. But yes, you are free to edit your question to add clarifying information that would help people look at your question.

If you feel the question is 100% perfect, and still not receiving attention, then it would be a great time to add a bounty on it. Don't be afraid to stop by Root Access, the Super User general room to ask for advice on the question too (how to fix the question more, not for answers... You may not like the answers we give in chat ;-) ).

Comment: Yes I know I should have mentioned the VPN issue - oops! I was going to just add it in but though that due to the lack of attention the question may be due a re-write with ALL the relevant information so held back until now.

Comment: So would it be okay to delete the question and just start over from scratch, if @JonnyWright wants to do that?

Comment: As long as he doesn't do it too much. If he does, he may get question banned